# Error 424 Object Required Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I'm trying to find the first record in the table that has my Active Field Name (Boolean) as True (-1).

It goes straight to error on the findfirst line. Please advise.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblinstalments", dbOpenDynaset)

With rs
rs.FindFirst "[Active] = -1"

If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No entry found"
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.MoveFirst` followed by `.Find`?  MSDN doesn't mention a `.FindFirst` method...

Comment: Hi Dave,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx

Comment: Get rid of `With rs` or get rid of `rs.`on the next line and add a `End With` after that.

Comment: @user6522953 My mistake, looked up ADO instead of DAO :)

Comment: LocEngineer - I do have an end with furthur down - if I remove the rs. then i get sub or function not defined.

Comment: Ah wait, totally overlooked that: `If rst.NoMatch` - it is `rs`not `rst`.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for helping but I just used a long way round: 
Do Until ![Active] = -1
   rs.MoveNext
   Loop